# Eclipse RCP Show tabs(Views) in two rows

Tags: rcp

I need show tabs in two rows, please can you help me?
I'm using ECLIPSE RCP.
I tried and used IFolderLayout but only show in one row.

Comment: There is no support for more that one row.

Answer (score 0):

In my view there is no support for more than one row.

But you can extend the ViewStack which uses AbstractPresentationFactory. U can write your know presentation logic eg : "NativeStackPresentation"

Thanks
Shashwat